# define function to be continuous

Tags: calculus

> the function $f(x)=x^{\frac{2}{1-x}}$ is defined to for a positive $x$ and $x\neq 1$ can you define the function at $x=1$ so it will be continuous there?

The answer is no, as the power is not defined at $x=1$?

Comment: You are right that the power is not defined at $x=1$. But the question is that can you define the function such that it is continuous at $x=1$. So really you try to add something to the definition of the function to make it continuous (if possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question isn't whether the *current definition* makes sense for $x=1$, but rather if it can be *extended* to allow $x$ to equal 1 in a nice way.

For instance, consider the function $f(x)={x\over x}$. This function is defined on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$; on the other hand, it's clear that we could just "fill in the hole" by defining a new function $\hat{f}$ as $\hat{f}(x)=f(x)$ if $x\not=0$, and $\hat{f}(x)=1$ if $x=0$. Then

- $\hat{f}$ *extends* $f$: whenever $f(x)$ is defined, so is $\hat{f}(x)$, and we have $f(x)=\hat{f}(x)$ if $f(x)$ is defined.
- $\hat{f}(0)$ is defined. (Unlike $f(0)$.)
- $\hat{f}$ is continuous at 0.

The question is whether something similar can be done here - is there a function $\hat{f}(x)$ such that

- $\hat{f}$ is defined on *all* positive reals,
- if $x$ is a positive real with $x\not=1$, then $\hat{f}(x)=f(x)$, and
- $\hat{f}$ is continuous at 1?

---

Based on the example of ${x\over x}$, can you tell what question about the original function, $f$, you need to answer in order to tell if it can be so extended? (HINT: it has to do with a limit . . .)

Comment: it seems like the only problem is at $x=1$ for all other x's the function is defined

Comment: @gbox Yes, the question is: "Can you **extend $f$** to a function which is defined the same way as $f$ wherever $f$ is defined, *but is also defined at 1*, and which is continuous at 1?" Do you understand the example I gave about $x\mapsto {x\over x}$ being extended to $x\mapsto 1$?

Comment: A hopefully helpful contrast: let $g(x)$ be defined on all nonzero reals as $g(x)=-1$ if $x<0$ and $g(x)=1$ if $x>0$. Then $g$ **cannot** be extended to a continuous function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Do you see why? (HINT: draw it . . .)

Answer (score 2):

We can rewrite $f(x)$ as $f(x) = [1+(x-1)]^\frac{-2}{x-1}$.
From here, we see that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} f(x) = e^{-2}.$$
Since the limit exists, we conclude that we can define $f(1) = e^{-2}$ to obtain a continuous function.

Comment: where did $e$ came from? I can not see it

Comment: $\lim (1+ x)^{\frac{1}{x}} = e} when $x \to 0$

Comment: How you have realized that is should be defined as $e^{-2}$?

Comment: It is a standard fact that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (1+x)^\frac{1}{x} = e$. Now substitute to get $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} (1+x-1)^\frac{1}{x-1} = e$. Raise this to the power of $-2$ to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The limit $x^{\frac{2}{(1-X)}}$ when $x \to 1$ is $e^{-2}$, so defining $f(1)=e^{-2}$ makes the function continuous.

To find the limit, let's look at $\ln$ of the function, $\frac{2\ln x}{1-x}$. The limit is $0/0. $ Using l'Hopital rule we have $-2/x, $ which equals -2 at $x=1. $ So the function's lim is $e^{-2}$